# Yii Framework how to call View from Controller?

Tags: php, yii

this is my controller file like.

```
class MyController extends CController
{
    /**
     * Index action is the default action in a controller.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        //call view file like abc.php
    }

}
```

this is my view/abc.php file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

how to call abc.php file into my controller.

Comment: You can get your answer: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app

Comment: Spend some time reading the documentation. Views should only have content that goes *into* the `<body>` tag; `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` should be emitted by a [layout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#layout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your abc.php file into the views/My directory and then write.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   $this->render('/abc');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   $this->render('abc', array(
        'model' => $model, // Model with the values to show on the view file.
    ));
}
```

Comment: i write that but i got error like : MyController cannot find the requested view "abc".

Comment: try with:'viewNameFolder/nameView'

Comment: @Daniel Vaquero: you didn't read the question correctly. His view is in the views/ folder, not under views/<controller name>.

Comment: @ParhamDoustdar him said her controller name it's : 'MyController', and in my code not use 'MyController' name in any site.. :S

Answer (score 0):

Move your abc.php file into the views/MyController directory, and then you can use `$this->render('abc.php');` function. As it currently stands, the view can be loaded using `$this->render('/abc.php');`. I'd also suggest you listen to the comments left by others: do not leave your view in views/, and do not output html and head and body tags and such in your view.

Comment: Yes, @ParhamDoustdar have the reason. Move your view to 'views/MyController directory'